# How do I reinstall the glass dome on my light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

Can't figure out how to get glass cover back into clips.  All three have springs but due to positioning, I can't hold all three fully back and get glass positioned in clips at the same time.  I keep thinking there must be a trick, but haven't figured it out if there is - any advice or do I need to go into the street and recruit another pair of hands and another ladder?

[image: Fixture]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the clips without the glass cover? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: what clips? ... i see none in the picture

Comment: just keep trying. i had one of those. a huge PITA. you have to bend it more than you want and keep fiddling until it suddenly submits to your will. LED bulbs highly recommended so you don't have to suffer again anytime soon.

Comment: Hello again. I took your edits to @DoxyLover's answers and put them into your question. And please: [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I'm guessing that rotation is critical. If you're off center the width of the glass grows quickly. Set the first clip exactly at the center of a side and press it outward, then work the other two over.

Comment: @isherwood - you were correct!  I didn't initially understand your reference but today my son came over and with his assistance holding two of the clips all the way open we were ultimately able to get the glass in place.  However, rotation is critical because otherwise, it is simply too wide to fit - good grief!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Without being able to see the clips, I’m still going to say to try placing the lip of the glass cover against two of the clips and then press against the opposite side of the cover: use the cover to press in the clips. You can then use your other hand to press in the remaining clip.

You may actually find that one of the clips is fixed. In this case, use the cover lip to press in the two mobile clips, raise the cover to fit under the fixed clip and then release pressure to let the cover lip slide into the fixed clip.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is critical. If you're off center with the first clip's position the width of the glass between clips grows quickly.

Set the first clip exactly at the center of a side and press it outward, then work the other two over.